# Passing a specific variable to a function and then edit the value of this variable

Tags: c++, pointers

Well, like my title says, i want to pass a variable to a function, which ones value will then be edited in a specific way and saved again in the variable. i don't want to make the function return the computed value, i want sth. like this:

```
    void function(variable_name, double computing_value)
    {
     variable_name *= computing_value;
    }
```

for example. it'd be more comfortable for me this way. (i want to program levels for a game with it). can i do sth. with pointers to get this? like, passing a pointer to the function, and then referring to the variable the pointer points at?

Comment: You can pass by reference or by pointer value and modify the value within the function.  What you have there is illegal as variable_name does not have a type.

Comment: yeah i know it'd be ridiculuos if it'd work like this ^^

Answer (score 3):

You want a reference type:

```
void function(double& variable_name, double computing_value)
{
  variable_name *= computing_value;
}
```

Here I've assumed that `variable_name` should be a `double`. A reference type allows you to pass an argument to the function without it begin copied. That is, `variable_name` will be a *reference* to the object that was passed in.

Note: do not mistake the `&` in the type as the "address of" operator. It's not. They are two different meanings for `&` in C++. Here we are using it for a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you no longer need pointers to modify a parameter. You can use a *reference* instead:

```
void function(T &t, T y) { // Where T is the type of your argument.
     t *= y;
}
```

In this case the parameter `y` will be copied, but not `t`. Since it is passed by reference no copy is needed; you're acting on the object itself.